# How do you deal with composite pattern when using hibernate and domain-driven design?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, domain-driven-design, composite

Does hibernate has support for hierarchical data in a database where

- you use a parentId
- you use a parentId and an orderId
- you use [Modified
  Preorder Tree Traversal](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/2)

Comment: You can try [this](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/16/how-to-map-a-tree-in-nhibernate)

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate supports Modified Preorder Tree Traversal in that lets you define the left/right properties. It does not support hierarchic queries however, but it's pretty trivial to re-hierarchize objects out of linear query if you order that by left value.

Answer (score 1):

Just found that the feature is in-progress

http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1395

Comment: It's always better to add some details rather than posting just a link. Don't you think?

Comment: the feature must be in progress for quite a while as it shows the creation date of the page referred as 25/Jan/06 3:05 PM. And it still isnt assisgned to anyone. Furthermore this isnt an answer to the question as the links doesn't solve the OPs problem...